# SQL return result if where clause doesn't match anything

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database with two tables: `trips` and `days`.  Each entry in `days` has an id that corresponds to an entry in `trips`.

I want to run a query that will return the trip that occurs on a provided date, and if there isn't one that occurs on that date then return the next trip after that date.  Here's my current query (`daystring` is generated in code, assume it's a valid SQL date string):

```
SELECT _id, number, date 
FROM trips 
INNER JOIN days ON trips._id = days.trips_id 
WHERE days.date > DATE( daystring, "start of day", "-1 day" ) 
  AND days.date < DATE( daystring, "start of day", "+1 day" );
```

That query only returns a result if a trip exists on the provided date though.  How can I modify it to return the next trip after that date only if there isn't one on that date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT _id, number, date FROM trips INNER JOIN days ON trips._id = days.trips_id 
WHERE days.date > DATE( daystring, "start of day", "-1 day" ) 
order by date Limit 1;
```

is a quick fix. Might want an index on the date column if you don't have one though.